# How to dynamic update the content of a Table with dynamic rows?

Tags: dynamic, gui-construction

I worked this way, but it does not work as expected:
The rows of the table:

```
nrows = Slider[Dynamic@n, {0, 5, 1}];
```

The contents of the table:

```
info = Dynamic@Table[<|"a" -> "", "b" -> ""|>, {i, n}]
```

The input form of the table:

```
dt = Dynamic @ Table[With[{i = i},
  <|"a" -> InputField[info[[1]][[i]][["a"]], String],
    "b" -> InputField[info[[1]][[i]][["b"]], String]
 |>
], {i, n}]
```

[image]

Why haven't the editing been updated to the table's content?

Also, if I predefine the table's rows, then the table will not be dynamic, but if I do not predefine it, the data will lose when shorten the table's rows. The first way is easy, I've already implemented it that way. So what I am really confused of is the second way. How can I implement the input form if I want the data to be forgotten if I shorten n, and at the same time, what I input into the form, the data I input will be dynamic updated in the table? Or, is there a way to define a table with dynamic rows without losing data when shorten the rows by a slider?

Comment: How changing `n` should affect already existing data?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Your question is just another problem I've been encountered with. I found I could only define a 5 row table and then use a dynamic slider to control the input form generated, but I could not change the row number of the table and generate a same length input form at the same time. So could you help me with that also.

Comment: I just want to use a slider to control a table's length and a dynamic form's length where the form presents the table's every element, and the edited value been updated to the table immediately.

Comment: Sure, but you still didn't answered my first comment, what should happen with entries when you shorten `n`, should they be forgotten? Maybe changing `n` should always reset the table?

Comment: Oh, that is a good question. If I predefine the table's rows, then the table will not be dynamic, but if I do not predefine it, the data will lose when shorten the table's rows. The first way is easy, I've already implemented it that way. So what I am really confused of is the second way. How can I implement the input form if I want the data to be forgotten if I shorten `n`, and at the same time, what I input into the form, the data I input will be dynamic updated in the table? Thanks!

Comment: Please edit the question with all relevant information. What are acceptable data inputs, is there a fixed structure or not. What exactly should happen when certain actions/events are triggered, etc etc. Once edited it will appear on Reopen review queue and if community decides it is clear enough they will vote to open.

Answer (score 5):

I think you can solve the problem as follows:

```
Row[{Slider[Dynamic[n], {0, 5, 1}], " n = ", Dynamic[n]}]

Dynamic[
    TableForm[
        Table[
            {
                InputField[Dynamic[Evaluate[Symbol["x" <> ToString[i]]]]], 
                InputField[Dynamic[Evaluate[Symbol["y" <> ToString[i]]]]]
            }, 
            {i, 1, n}
        ]
    ]
]


Dynamic[
    TableForm[
        Table[
            <|
                "x" <> ToString[i] -> Symbol["x" <> ToString[i]], 
                "y" <> ToString[i] -> Symbol["y" <> ToString[i]]
            |>, 
            {i, 1, n}
        ]
    ]
]
```

I received the following:

[image]

Comment: But I am afraid I cannot take this way to solve this problem. We use a lot of fields in associations so I think it is not a good way to rename every key to a symbol to assoc a value and then assoc to the association.